# Jquery accordion animation stops it working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery accordion that works fine without animation:

```
jQuery('#countrylist').accordion({
    active: false, 
    alwaysOpen: false, 
    autoHeight: false,
    animated: false
});
```

But if I try to use animation it no longer works:

```
jQuery('#countrylist').accordion({
   active: false, 
   alwaysOpen: false, 
   autoHeight: false,
   animated: "bounceslide"
});
```

Now clicking on one of the heading links no longer opens that div, it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-animated), you need to include UI Effects Core in your page as well:

> Choose your favorite animation, or
>   disable them (set to false). In
>   addition to the default, 'bounceslide'
>   and all defined easing methods are
>   supported (**'bounceslide' requires UI
>   Effects Core**)

(emphasis mine)

I'm pretty sure this is it since your code works fine for me when I include jQueryUI in its entirety: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/86xGs/1/